# Should workboxJS replace usage of sw-precache?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, sw-precache, workbox

Following the 1.0.0 release of [WorkboxJS](https://workboxjs.org/), should this be used as a replacement for [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache)?

From my limited experience it seems to include all the awesome from `sw-precache' and`sw-toolbox` and much more. In their own words:

> The next version of sw-precache & sw-toolbox.
>
> Workbox is a rethink of our previous service worker libraries with a focus on modularity. It aims to reduce friction with a unified interface, while keeping the overall library size small. Same great features, easier to use and cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you read it right that workbox is the successor of both of these, and it do include precaching and dynamic route handling. 
However if you find any feature parity missing from the abouve two feel free to open a dicussion thread here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox